# Symfony Doctrine entity friend hasFriend followers

Tags: symfony, entity, entity-relationship, friend

I need to set follower, following (myFriends) hasFriend logic to my project. column "odobera" means "following" to example nick(id user) odobera (following to this user). User (25) is following user(37).

Requests table:

[image]

```
 User entity:  

    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TB\RequestsBundle\Entity\Requests", mappedBy="odobera")
 */
protected $followers;    

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TB\RequestsBundle\Entity\Requests", mappedBy="nick")
 */
protected $myFriends; 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
     $this->followers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
     $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
/**
 * Get myFriends
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getMyFriends()
{
    return $this->myFriends;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param \TB\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasFriend(User $user)
{
    return $this->myFriends->contains($user);
}  

 class Requests
 {

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TB\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="myFriends")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nick", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $nick;    

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TB\UserBundle\Entity\User",inversedBy="followers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="odobera", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $odobera;
```

In controller:

```
       $myFollowers=$user->getMyFriends();
```

returns:

[image]

What is good: returns 1 record. I actually follow just one person as you can see here the id of record is 24395

DB requests table:

[image]

I don't know if is good that getMyFriends function returns response in that "format". Please look at it carefully.

Then I have select followers from query and in loop:

```
{% for follower in followers %}
    and i print data like this (works greate) {{ follower.nick }} 
            or if i want some fields from user entity {{ follower.nick.rank }} 
 {% endfor %}
```

But the problem is here:

```
 {% if (app.user.hasFriend(follower.nick)) %}
```

That returns false, why? I follow this user as I checked in controller with dump :P Few lines over.

Comment: What does `{{ dump(app.user) }}` render?

Comment: This: http://pastebin.com/GVK60wdd

Comment: So if you do the `for` loop but with `{% for friend in friends %}` you can see the `follower.nick` you are looking for?

Comment: no no sure not it cames from return $this->render('RequestsBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('followers'=>$followers)); and i made a query for $followers in controller. This part of script is good imo.

Comment: Yes sorry I wanted to write `{% for friend in app.user.friends %}`

Comment: hm... you mean... myFriends ? Or ... dont know little be what's your point sir :)

Comment: No my point being: when you call `{% if (app.user.hasFriend(follower.nick)) %} ` it checks if inside `app.user.friends` it finds the object `follower.nick` right? So if you enumerate what's inside `app.user.friends` and don't see the object `follower.nick` then your `if` returning `false` is fine! :)

Comment: Hm... but in my entity you can see that this function check property myFriends(people who follow me)            public function hasFriend(User $user)
    {
        return $this->myFriends->contains($user);
    } but the point keeps right? just you mistaken a variable

Comment: Right, so if you run `{% for friend in app.user.myfriends %}` (no typo this time!) do you see the `User` you are looking for?

Comment: i edited my comment before you add new heh i see your typo and the point keeps: i wrote {% for friend in app.user.myFriends %} (where should be theoreticly people who i follow as you can check the entity) and then: {{ friend.nick }} but it wrote just MY NICK (299times) - this is count of user i follow to.

Comment: You've probable seen it but the doctrine documentation example seems close to what you have: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing Does it help?

Comment: yes i was trying to do it this way but i couldn't have self referencing because of another fields in requests table.

Comment: i am pretty desperate... if you would help me i would reward you a little be... :/

Comment: Well I start to be short on idea but can you post your `TB\RequestsBundle\Entity\Requests` entity?

Comment: Here please: http://pastebin.com/LJXGkKK4 it can't be so hard :/ Its nothing extra hm :/

Comment: So your entities `User` and `Requests` are the same?

Comment: No here is my user entity http://pastebin.com/74YBuYnd

Comment: If you do `{% for friend in app.user.myfriends %}` and then `{{ dump(friend) }}` what do you get?

Comment: This: http://pastebin.com/yESk5NH8

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are comparing two different type variable.

When you do this: `{% if (app.user.hasFriend(follower.nick)) %}` the following function is called:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param \TB\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasFriend(User $user)
{
    return $this->myFriends->contains($user);
}
```

This function is called, taking a `User` type `$user` variable and you then use the `contains()` function on `$this->myFriends`.
`$this->myFriends` is an `ArrayCollection` of `Requests` (so different type than `User`) and from the doctrine documentation about `contains()`:

> The comparison of two elements is strict, that means not only the
>   value but also the type must match.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

Comment: hm.... thx a lot for try help! you can see people vote this question. And what should i do know could tell me please? Thx!

Comment: Then the solution depends on you. Can you somehow change `$nick` to be a `Request`? Does that make sense in your website? Or can you write a different `hasFriend()` function checking for example the ids instead of the whole object?

Comment: hm... i think ... yes .. i am not much good at it but the point of hasFriend function is just check if user who i want to check ... is in my friends... i dont care about more :P That's the point. + to be able from $user-> getMyFriends and dont had to requesting another entity in ctrl myself. I would be extremly happy if you could paste some code here. All documents you have in this post heh :P Because after 3days i am not sure i can complete it :/

Comment: This is really something you should do on your end. If you encounter other errors don't hesitate to ask other questions!

Comment: Okay i will try hopefully somehow will do it... but i am confused... in previous comments you ask about myFriends and dump... and i told you it still rendered just my name in the loop... is the entity ok ? Or ... ahi am really confused in this phase

Comment: You have a `User` objects and the people your user is following are `User` as well. But then, the people following you are typed `Requests`. But this is more about your application global goal and features so I can't really help on this...

Comment: Hm... but okay lets say comparing doesnt work's because of different type of user... but when i have      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TB\RequestsBundle\Entity\Requests", mappedBy="nick")
     */
    protected $myFriends;  to check users i follow to... why then in  {% for friend in app.user.myFriends %} it renders just ME ME ME ME ME and still ME ?

Comment: You should review your database schema and see if it makes sense depending on what you want to realize. I really can't help to do this but this is what I would do. If it makes sense, I would then try to understand why all the followers attached to the current user are the same.

Comment: hm.. okay just a question for sure:     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TB\RequestsBundle\Entity\Requests", mappedBy="nick")
     */
    protected $myFriends;  this means that this property is connected to the "nick" property in requests entity and when nick looks like this:  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TB\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="myFriends")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nick", referencedColumnName="id") then it means all the records in this column are users and it automaticly withdrawn people who follow me? or not? ?