# Boolean logic doesn't work as I expect in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, boolean-logic, extends

```
 {{ dump(extend) }}
```

Result:

```
  boolean false
```

And when I want to make this:

```
{% if extend is true %}
    {% extends 'WelcomePageBundle:Default:welcome_page.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

It doesn't work. Why?

Error:

```
The test "false" does not exist in FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword.html.twig at line 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has to be either `{% if extend %}` — because `extend` is already a boolean — or `{% if extend == true %}`. `is` is used for [tests](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/index.html); not for comparison.

Comment: ofc i tried but the result is: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Node "1" does not exist for Node "Twig_Node"

Comment: The error you're getting is not related to the question; you're getting it for other reasons. See [Conditional Inheritance](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#conditional-inheritance) for insights.

Comment: hm... ah ok will try do it somehow else .. and can you please check on this: i am ultra desperate here :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074830/symfony-doctrine-entity-friend-hasfriend-followers#comment21208451_15074830 thx!

Comment: watch out as well because 'true' has to be in lowercase (i.e. `inProduction == True` will fail)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`empty`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/empty.html) test:

> Test empty checks if a variable is empty (null, false, empty array, or empty string).

```
{% if extend is not empty %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Take a look at the [list of available tests](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/index.html) as well as [logic operators](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#logic) from the official Twig documentation.